How to open this code editor file from GitHub with Godot and Mac?
There is a YouTuber named FaceDev, and he created a code editor. I want to try that code editor, but it's not supported on macOS. However, people are saying it's possible to like get around borders and access it on mac: https://github.com/face-hh/griddycode/issues. I downloaded Godot and ran the GitHub file, but this is the only thing that pops up: Link To a Youtube Video of Me Showing Whats Happening When I Run it.. So my problem is, can someone tell me steps or how I can open and run this code editor on my mac or MacOS.

You can compile it within Godot yourself. The same way you would compile a game in Godot.

then you can compile it to macOS by clicking macOS and changing some settings.

Youtube HowTo tutorial!:
https://youtu.be/Dre2OGiORck

How do you compile it @Ash, can you send a youtube video on your side on how to do it ?

@TheSilentCoder I'll do it in a few hours. Busy rn, just give me the bounty before we forget :}

Hey Ash, did you get the award? Anyway, please send tutorial because I need it.

i added the youtube video to the original answer! ;D
Would be nice if you could mark it as an answer :>
And yes, i got the award, thank you

I marked it as answer, sorry I don't know much about stack overflow, thank you.
